# Multiple periodic ajax updates in jquery; correct?

Tags: jquery, django, celery

After an evening of browsing and trying i have something working but i wonder if this is all correct, or can it be improved. I ask since i'm not using javascript nor jquery/ajax often....

In a django application i have a celery task running and i would like to update the browser with the results when the task is done.

For this i create a javascript timer using setTimeout (so i can stop it on success).

Now i wanted to be able to support multiple timers; one for each field (or task) i want to update; i'm not sure how i could set a new timeout on an anonymous function, so i gave it a name and made it global; is that correct? Is there a better way of doing this?

Paul Bormans

```
{% block jscript %}
<script>
function updateTaskResult(i, e) {
$.ajax({
  type: "GET",
  url: "{% url 'task_status' %}",
  cache: false,
  data: {task_id: e.id},
  context: e
}).done(function(json) {
    $(e).html("state=" + json.state + " result=" + json.result);
    if(json.state !== "{{ success }}") {
        setTimeout(updateTaskResult, 1000, i, e);
    }
});
}

$("div.status").each(function(i, e) {
    updateTaskResult(i,e);
});
</script>
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 1):

To avoid the globals, you can wrap your code in an anonymous function that is run immediately.  This creates a private variable scope for you to work in.

Also, as you don't use the keyword **this** in your AJAX callback, there is no need to set the context to **e**.

```
<script>
    (function() {
        var updateTaskResult = function (i, e) {
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "{% url 'task_status' %}",
                cache: false,
                data: {task_id: e.id},
            }).done(function(json) {
                $(e).html("state=" + json.state + " result=" + json.result);

                if(json.state !== "{{ success }}") {
                    setTimeout(updateTaskResult, 1000, i, e);
                }
            });
        }

        $("div.status").each(function(i, e) {
            updateTaskResult(i,e);
        });
    })();
</script>
```

Anonymous functions can be used with setTimeout like this:

```
<script>
    setTimeout(function () {
        // Do stuff.
    }, 1000);
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to be aware that this is a waste of resources. It isn'tn the right thing to do.
What you want to do is to implement `PUSH`.

For this with django, checkout [evserver](http://code.google.com/p/evserver/wiki/Documentation), "Lightweight Asynchronous Python WSGI Server".
It seems promising.
Also, checkout [diesel.io](http://diesel.io/).
This way, you will have your server push data into your browser only when there is some data to push (you wont need to check t from the client side).

If you use celery, I presume that you are not scared of tinkering with python,
so do it right.